# Can Network Manager settings be made to survive a reboot?

Tags: network-manager

When I right click on the nm-applet and choose to disable wireless, it turns wireless off.  Fair enough, but when I reboot, wireless is magically back on again.

That's just an example, but more generally, in a system with multiple cards, can network manager be made to remember their status?  (Like the way Windows will allow you enable/disable a NIC).

I believe that you can disable a NIC permanently by editing files, but I'm hoping for a more ad-hoc situation - if it would just remember my choice, that would be grand.

[image]

Comment: Please consider filling a bug report about this if you can't find one already.

Comment: This question is probably relevant: [Disable wireless on startup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3677/disable-wireless-on-startup)

Comment: Thanks ændrük.  There's no perfect answers in that question, sadly.  I think I'll be better off filing a bug about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right click on the icon in the notification area
- Edit Connections...
- Click on the connection
- Click Edit
- Untick/uncheck "Connect automatically"
- Click Apply

Should work.

Or if you want to disable wireless, many laptops have a physical switch to disable wireless.  Obviously that is remembered until you turn the switch back to On.

Comment: That's a good point.  Doesn't your WIFI card from broadcasting away in the background though.  I'll accept this answer for you Mikel, since I don't think there's a way to do what I'm wanting currently.