# Disable wlan0 -device permanently

Tags: wireless, startup

I executed unsuccessfully [the following line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3677/disable-wireless-on-startup) in /etc/rc.local with permissions 755:

> sudo ifdown 00:1f:9c:c3:b3:77

where the last word is presenting the address of my wlan0 device.

Having the command `rfkill block $IP-address-Of-my-wlan0` in startup scripts is not possible solution, since Network-manager is able to change soft-blocks.

You cannot configure each device separately in *Network tools* or in *Network manager*.  If you change one setting the setting applies to other wifi -device too. I cannot use WICD because I need Network Manager's Mobile Broadband -feature.

**How can you put a permanent software block to the given wifi -device in Ubuntu 11.10 at each startup such that other programs such as Network manager do not change it?**

There is probably a file which permissions are only needed to be changed to 700 to disallow for example Network Manager to reach the device wlan0.
**How can you give only the user the permission to touch the device wlan0?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simply not possible to block root access to a file without using something like AppArmor or SELinux.

As long as your two WLAN devices use different drivers, this method should work for you:

First, determine which driver you are using.  In my case, from this output:

`mark@xiii:/var/log$ sudo dmesg | grep -e 'Ethernet' -e 'WiFi'`

`...jme 0000:07:00.5: eth0: JMC250 Gigabit Ethernet chiprev:23....[SNIP]`
`...iwlagn: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:`

So this tells me my wifi driver is "iwlagn".  I can either append `blacklist iwlagn` to a file in /etc/modprobe.d/ or create a new file, perhaps /etc/modprobe.d/my-personal-blacklist.conf that only contains the line `blacklist iwlagn`.

Comment: My dmesg does not have any word Ethernet nor WiFi. Please, see my dmesg output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/696718/. - My Ubuntu 11.10 is at the moment very broken so ignore the other abnormalities.

Comment: My other question related to the topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62937/to-enable-external-wlan-emitter-at-startup-automatically-by-etc-rc-local-or-othe

Comment: Hi Masi.  It looks like you haven't rebooted in while and it's rolled over somewhat.  It's missing the initial device initialization.  Can you do a fresh reboot and look again (and repost if needed)?  That should capture it.

Comment: I get the following dmesg's output this time: iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG

Comment: My dmesg is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/696753/

Comment: So yep, that's the one.  just replace "iwlagn" from my suggestion with "iwl3945" and hopefully you'll be good!  That should prevent the driver from loading and effectively disable it.