# How can I disable wlan by default in the network manager?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, network-manager

I use Ubuntu Mate 16.04.  I do not use wlan usually, but if I need it, I want wlan to be available.  To disable wlan, I deselect “Enable Wi-Fi” in the network manager's applet.  This seems to succesfully turn of wlan, but doesn't survive a reboot.  How can I permanently deselect the “Enable Wi-Fi” option such that (a) that configuration survives a reboot and (b) I can enable wlan through the network manager applet if needed?

Answer (score 1):

It is strange that disabled wifi doesn't survive reboots. It does here.

You could use the `rfkill`, which is a "tool for enabling and disabling wireless devices". (see `man rfkill for more info`)

To disable wifi, run `sudo rfkill block wifi`.

To re-enable, run `sudo rfkill unblock wifi`.

If all works as expected, just add `rfkill block wifi` to /etc/rc.local

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I would prefer an answer that addresses the cause instead of working around the error though.  Perhaps the relevant configuration file has improper permissions or something.  I wasn't even able to find which configuration file is relevant, perhaps you could help me with that.